# The debug type is not recognized "type": "node"

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

> The debug type is not recognized. Make sure you've got a corresponding
>   debug extension installed and that it is enabled.

`vscode v. 1.23.1
 node v. 7.9.0
 windows 10`

Node Debug build in extension is enabled. Restarted vscode multiple times to no avail. It used to work just up until yesterday, not sure what much has changed to cause that "not recognized" warning. Also, it doesn't appear when clicking the Add Configuration... button.

Answer (score 9):

There seem to be 2 Node Debug extensions. One that doesn't appear at first glance is "Node Debug (legacy)". The problem with my project was that it was disabled for some reason.

How I fixed it:

1. Find "Node Debug (legacy)" extension
2. Enable and reload vscode

Comment: Is this still valid in 2021?

Comment: @Marc judging by the 4k views, where the last upvote was a year ago, there could be something else to it, though I can't confirm

Answer (score 2):

The fix to me was to uninstall the extension then install it back.

Comment: This also worked for the aws-sam extension which gave me the same issue. I uninstalled the AWS Toolkit extension and reinstalled and it worked. Yay.

Answer (score 1):

In case it can help someone, one day... I got this issue (april 2022). To fix it, I had to run those VSCode commands:

1. `Disable All Installed Extensions`
2. `Enable All Extensions`

Comment: For me it was the `JavaScript Debugger` VSCode extension that was installed but disabled.  Simply clicking enable was enough to fix this error.

Comment: @Jthorpe Had the exact experience.

Comment: This worked and fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

please install the extension [JavaScript Debugger (Nightly)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly)

the "Node Debug (legacy)" extension is deprecated.